# Java Script: Setting Value to the Object by id, where id is last letter of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

As for the heading: it seems a little bit confusing but it is not.

In React I'm doing re-usability of code

I have

```
state={
       colorObj1: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'1'},
       colorObj2: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'0'},
       colorObj3: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'1'},
       colorObj4: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'0'},
       colorObj5: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'1'}
      }
```

I want this function --> By Id of Object, I want to set the color to a particular Object.

id value --> 1,2,3,4,5

```
getSelectedColor=(color,id) => {
    this.setState({colorObj{`id`}: color})  //WRONG CODE
}
```

Comment: `this.setState({['colorObj' + id]: color})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) as follow:

```
this.setState({[`colorObj${id}`]: color})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a react issue. You want to connect string with dynamic variable. You can use: 'someBasicStr'+dynamicVar or with template string(es6+): `someBasicStr${dynamicVar}`, any variable will be inside ${}.

Comment: so concept name is dynamic variable :D

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.state={
      colorObj1: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'1'},
      colorObj2: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'0'},
      colorObj3: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'1'},
      colorObj4: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'0'},
      colorObj5: {r:'0',g:'0',b:'0',a:'1'}
    }
  }

  setSelectedColor(color,id) {
    this.state['colorObj'+id]=color;
  }

  getSelectedColor(id) {
    return this.state['colorObj'+id];
  }
}


// TEST
let c = new MyClass();
c.setSelectedColor({r:'1',g:'1',b:'1',a:'1'},6)
console.log(c.getSelectedColor(6));
console.log(c.getSelectedColor(2));
```